# Generating an error when user does not input a multiple of 5 cents (between 5 and 100)

Tags: c++, if-statement, logic, modulo

I am trying to get my program to display an error message when I do not enter a multiple of 5 cents (between 5 and 100) such as 0.12. It does everything it needs to be doing (to my satisfaction), but this is something I have not been able to figure out. Although I enter an invalid input, it still gives me the results, instead of displaying an error.  I was thinking that perhaps using the fmod feature inside the if statement would help me to. I think my problem lies within a logic error that I cannot see. I would appreciate if I could get some guidance as to how I can go about this. Thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

 using namespace std;

int main()
{   double Dollar_Bill= 1.00;
    double QUARTERS= 0.25;
    double DIMES= 0.10;
    double NICKELS = 0.05;
    double Amount_Entered= 0.00;






//where I believe using fmod inside the parenthesis (Amount_Entered == 0.00) would be useful
if( Amount_Entered == 0.00)
{



    cout<<"Please enter a purchase amount (5-100) : \n";
    cin >> Amount_Entered;



    double Change= Dollar_Bill- Amount_Entered;

    double Q_Change = Change/QUARTERS;
    double D_Change = fmod( Change, QUARTERS)/0.10;
    double N_Change = fmod( Change,QUARTERS)/0.10;



    cout<<"You entered an amount of: "<<Amount_Entered<<" cents."<<endl;
    cout<<"Your change of "<<Change<<" is given as: "<<static_cast<int>(Q_Change)<<" Quarters, "<<static_cast<int>(D_Change)<<" Dime(s), and "<<static_cast<int>(N_Change)<<" Nickel(s)."<<endl;


    double Num_of_Coins = static_cast<int>(Q_Change) + static_cast<int>(D_Change) + static_cast<int>(N_Change);

    cout<<"The value of your "<< static_cast<int>(Num_of_Coins) <<" coins adds up to:"<< Change<<"cents."<<endl;

   cout<<"Thank you for using my program."<<endl;
 }

//perhaps something can go here? Such as an else if statement?
else
{
    cout<<"Unable to process amount entered. Please enter a valid amount."<<endl;

}

return 0;
}
```

---

I had made one using int values, but still have the same trouble.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Dollar_Bill = 100;
    int Quarters = 25;
    int Dimes = 10;
    int Nickels = 5;
    int Amount_Entered = 0;

    if (Amount_Entered %5 == 0)

    { cout<<"Please enter a purchase amount (5-100)"<<endl;
      cin>> Amount_Entered;

      int change = Dollar_Bill - Amount_Entered;

      int Q_change = change/Quarters;
      int D_change = (change%Quarters)/10;
      int N_change = (change%Quarters)/10;

      cout<<"You entered an amount of: "<< Amount_Entered<<" cents"<<endl;
      cout<<"Your change of "<<change<<" is given as: "<<Q_change<<"Quarter(s)"<<D_change<<" Dime(s)"<<N_change<<" Nickel(s)"<<endl;

      int Num_of_Coins = Q_change + D_change + N_change;

        cout<<"The value of your "<<Num_of_Coins<<" coins add up to: "<<change<<"cents."<<endl;
        cout<<"Thank you for using my program."<<endl;
    }


    else
    {
        cout<<"Unable to process an invalid amount purchase amount of "<<Amount_Entered<<"cents."<<endl;
        cout<<"Thank you for using my program."<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: And what´s the problem with writing a fmod inside of `()`? Side note: There are some potential problems if you expect doubles to hold exact values. I would change the program to work with cent only (or how the smallest subunit of your country´s dollar is named). Ie. instead of 4.23 dollar, save 423 cent, and use int instead of double.

Comment: Reminds me of the puzzle question: "Can you make 55 cents with exactly two coins, when one is not allowed to be a 5 cent piece?"

Answer (score 1):

Your approach here is flawed, but this is obviously a homework question so I'll try to give you a hint to get back on track.

First off, convert all the types to integers with units of cents. This will simplify the math. operator== on doubles probably won't give you the result you expect most of the time, same with operator/, due to precision and rounding.

What you want to research is integer division. For integers, operator/ will give you the quotient, and operator% will give you the remainder, which is sort of perfect for your application.

Ex:

```
int money = 80; //cents
int numQuarters = money / 25; // == 3 quarters
int remainingChange = money % 25; // == 5 cents
```

It should be relatively simple to daisy-chain this to other coin values.